# How should I organize the controller(s) for a model with differing views for the same action(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, code-organization, project-organization

I have a User model that, in my mind, has two show actions:

- A 'show' performed on a user's own record (to view their private profile)
- A 'show' performed other user records (to view their public profile)

I've thought of several different ways I *could* organize and implement this functionality, but I'm curious what the 'Rails Way' is to do it.

The URLs should be distinct (domain.com/account vs. domain.com/profile/someuser), which naturally leads me to the desire to have multiple views to represent the different viewpoints of this action.

Option one would be to create two controllers with a different show action and view to serve the requests.

Option two would be to place both actions in one controller with action names that are essentially duplicates (or forced non-duplicates, such as 'show' vs. 'show_public').

Option three would be to use one controller and one action that processes each request conditionally based on some unique bit of data: the route from which it was called, whether or params[:id] is populated, etc.

What's the 'Rails Way' to do this?

Comment: I don't know that there is a 'Rails Way' to organise your controllers. I'd do whatever feels most natural to your application. Ultimately, whatever you decide, it's best to have comprehensive tests so that you can change at a later date without fear of breaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `routes`, `controller` method and `view` for any user, nothing special here.

For `current_user`:

- pick an authentication gem (e.g. authlogic) with a `current_user` feature
- add a `route`, e.g. `/me`
- in the user controller, define a new method, e.g.: me (similar to show) which always use `current_user` to fetch @user
- a new `me.html.erb` view to display current user specific information

Hope it helps

Comment: This is essentially what I did. I created a one-off route to /profile/:id, then had that render the show_public_profile action/view. My existing show method continues to show the current user's profile.